# Deploying Django with Docker on Amazon Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a conceptual question here-
I'm looking to deploy a Django application on Elastic Beanstalk (which I've successfully done before) using a Docker (which I have yet to succeed with). I know the Elastic Beanstalk image prebuilt with Docker uses Ngnix, which I've deployed Django with before, but I'm a little lost on the accomplishing this on Elastic Beanstalk. I've used Amazon's documentation and successfully deployed a Dockerfile to elastic beanstalk using their code, but have yet to get it going on my own. Has anyone been successful with this? Can anyone point me in the right direction to find out how to accomplish this specific task? Thank you

Comment: Is there any reason why you are wrapping your Django app in Docker as opposed to running it right on Elastic Beanstalk? EB supports [Python & Django](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Python_django.html). Also, if you do want to use Docker, as long as you get it working locally, then the only issue is getting it to work with Elastic Beanstalk. It should only take a few tweaks to work.

Comment: I'm actually not an advocate of using Docker. I'm more an advocate of using Python/Django directly. Unfortunately this decision was made by a higher-up. That is a good point though. I suppose I should keep plugging away to get Docker working locally before working with Elastic Beanstalk.

Comment: Cool, once you get it working locally, it'll be pretty easy to get it to work with Elastic Beanstalk. Once you get that far, feel free to ping me anyway. My info is in my profile.

Comment: This issue has since been solved. I'll post the answer later on today.

Comment: I've decided to convert the solution to a Github hosted project. I will be posting a link & explanation soon.

Comment: I'd love to hear how you solved it. I'm struggling with Django/Docker deployment to EB as well.

Comment: @rfj001 If you're pressed to get it figured out, my email is listen on my profile. Feel free to drop me a line and I can write you an explanation. I'd rather not take the time to explain it here until I have the code to go with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so StackOverflow is being a pain about posting this answer (Seems to not like all the config snippets). So here's the link to the Github https://github.com/AndrewSmiley/django-docker-eb. Basically the README is the post I tried to add here to StackOverflow, but unsuccessfully.

Comment: This does not work with Python3 currently.

Supervisor requires Python 2.4 or later but does not work on any version of Python 3.  You are using version 3.5.0 (default, Nov 11 2015, 10:39:25)